# O que seria uma conta irregular no Stack Overflow em Português?

Tags: suporte, contas-usuário

Dia 30/03/2021 eu estava conferindo as perguntas dos usuários novatos e me deparei com essa pergunta:
<sub>https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/502914/sobrecarga-de-construtores-e-heran%c3%a7a</sub>

[image: Imagem da pergunta para quem não tem reputação suficiente para abrir o link]

Repentinamente a tela mudou e o moderador [Comunidade♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade), que é próprio sistema, havia removido e bloqueado a pergunta como SPAM ([O histórico de revisões dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/502914/revisions)).

Fiquei assustado, na minha mente vieram coisas como em Exterminador do Futuro e  Matrix, e sinalizei a publicação. Ingenuamente achei que a imagem fosse o problema, mas pelo jeito não foi. Esta é minha sinalização:

> O sistema sinalizou automaticamente como spam, é uma pergunta comum
> com o código publicado em bitmap. Não suspendam a conta como spammer.
> – Augusto Vasques 5 horas atrás   rejeitado - **Não foi o sistema, a
> postagem vem de conta irregular**.

Não sei se pode ser dito, por questões de segurança, mas em todo caso eu fiquei curioso em saber:

- O que seriam contas irregulares no Stack Overflow em Português?
- O que torna uma conta no Stack Overflow em Português irregular?
- Uma conta irregular pode se tornar uma conta regular?

Comment: Uma pessoa que cometeu coisas irregulares no site, o regular é o "comum", ou melhor, é o que é considerado a maneira adequada de agir no site, atividade incomuns (irregulares) podem inicialmente serem suspeitas e depois confirmadas ou não, nesse caso foi confirmado que o autor fez algo, provavelmente não nessa postagem dele, ele pode ter feito diversas coisas que vocês não chegaram a ver, pois o moderador interceptou antes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, tem algo que o surpreendeu como moderador, que para um usuário comum passaria batido?

Comment: Todos os dias temos que lidar com atitudes que não chegam aos olhos dos outros, tem muitos usuários, as vezes até alguns veteranos, que foram pegos fazendo coisas irregulares, temos algumas ferramentas para facilitar detectar isso, não é tudo que dá para notar, muito depende de nós humanos buscar indícios. Uma conta só é bloqueada quando comprovada as atividades irregulares. Tem gente que é evidente logo nas primeiras postagens, então removemos tão rápido que vocês nem ficam sabendo. PS: parece divertido, mas na verdade é cansativo as vezes :)

Comment: Eu não posso falar sobre o que ocorre nos bastidores, mas garanto que já fiquei de cabelo em pé e já tivemos que "correr" algumas vezes para impedir que coisas muito ruins atingissem outros usuários da comunidade, atitudes "irregulares" de pessoas que realmente queriam prejudicar a comunidade. Antes de ser MOD eu não imaginava que tinham pessoas complicadas assim aqui no site.

Comment: Essa é minha preocupação em não ficar especulando, sei que tem coisas que você não pode expor. Mas eu queria muito saber de tudo :D

Comment: Olha, teve coisas que eu queria apagar da minha memória hehehe. Bom, se quer uma opinião, se envolver com pessoas problemáticas não é nada produtivo, estamos aqui para evitar ao máximo que esse tipo de pessoas atinjam vocês, então prefira **"querer saber de tudo o que é útil"**, tem coisas muito melhores para se envolver e produzir.

Comment: É divertido no começo, depois é um porre que tenha tanta gente que faz tanta coisa errada de forma insistente. Tem um cara que parou agora, eu acho, que criou dezenas de contas tentando burlar o sistema, logo falaremos em centenas se ele insistir. E sabe o mais engraçado? Essas pessoas costumam dizer "me falaram que estão prejudicando muito usuário desse jeito", o que faz parecer que todas fraudes vem no mesmo lugar. Quase todas mensagens enviadas para usuários problemáticos, vem com ironia, inversão de papéis ou coisas piores. Não imaginam o que tivemos que aguentar por esses dias.

Comment: @Maniero, você pode falar por alto sobre esses acontecimentos recente ou tem deixar em off?

Comment: Tem muitos, não é um caso só. Tem um mentirosos absurdos, é pior que terraplanismo, tem coisas bem ofensivas, tem pessoas que são insistentes demais, ou os que acham que a situação ficará melhor pra eles de alguma forma se nos ofender, se falar mal do site, se mostrar que a presença dele é a melhor coisa que o poderia acontecer no site e como ele vai embora ficará ruim. Já recebemos fotos cujo objetivo seria nos chocar, mas foi só cômico.

Comment: Imagino que a vida de moderador não deve ser fácil. Felizmente só algumas poucas vezes vi coisas que sinalizei, acho que só foram duas de comentários bem agressivos, em geral que me lembro são propagandas, mas como disseram, isso é o que passa e chega pra gente, a realidade deve ser bem pior, kudos para os moderadores pelo trabalho, pq passo um bom tempo aqui e não vejo muita coisa, sinal que muito é filtrado

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Este é um assunto específico da conta, como pode notar o usuário não existe mais.

Alguns esclarecimentos:

- O sistema não agiu sobre flag de "spam" e sim "rude ou abusivo".
- Abusivo nem sempre é contra outro usuário, no caso houve uma ocorrência de abuso do sistema
- O usuário que fez a postagem não poderia tê-la feito, e usou um artifício (uma conta nova).
- Não é permitido usar mais de uma conta para contornar bloqueio de outra.
- Flags de spam e de abuso, quando efetivadas, imediatamente bloqueiam e escondem o conteúdo das postagens, para minimizar danos (além da remoção, tem um bloqueio de conteúdo)

Como pode ver pelo histórico, depois de sanado o problema da conta irregular, eu restaurei a postagem e refiz o fechamento adequado, e a remoção "comum" (sem o bloqueio) para que a pergunta voltasse ao estado natural de outras postagens fechadas no site, restaurando o acesso dos usuários privilégio de ver posts deletados. Minha restauração eliminou o bloqueio, aí fiz só a remoção "comum", sem flag.

Detalhe é que a primeira vez que removi esqueci de fechar o post antes, então refiz o processo, desta vez com o fechamento correto, e só depois remoção. Note que não precisava ter tido esse trabalho todo, é só um cuidado extra.

Se fosse uma postagem com problema no conteúdo (ofensivo, phishing, etc) teria mantido mais restrita. No caso o conteudo em si não vai causar dano aos usuários com menos privilégios, assim, facilitei o acesso.